# Чи існує слово фік?

Tags: існування-слова

Існує цікаве слово "фанфік".

Фанфік (англ. Fan fiction, англ. fanfiction або наступні скорочення англ. fan fic, fanfic, fic) — жаргонізм, що описує аматорський твір за мотивами популярних оригінальних літературних творів, творів кіномистецтва (кінофільмів, телесеріалів, аніме та ін.), коміксів (в тому числі — манги), а також відеоігор, тощо.

Нещодавно зустріла слово "фік". Я так розумію, що це похідне від "фанфік". Чи навпаки) Але в мережі жодної інформації про "фік" не знайшла. Воно взагалі існує?)

Answer (score 1):

У статті [Фанфіки на уроках словесності](http://tsybulyanskabigmirnet.blogspot.com/2012/08/blog-post_27.html) є інформація, що **фіки** - це автори фанфіків:

> А ось і словник юних фікрайтерів, або **фіків** (авторів фанфіків).

В статті [Філологічний експрес: Про фанфіків](https://irynadenysjuk.blogspot.com/2014/12/blog-post_2.html) **фіками** називають у ролі синоніма фанфіки:

> Одні автори пишуть, дочекавшись натхнення, придумуючи з  голови в довільному порядку, потім вичитуючи, переставляючи місцями і створюючи цілісний твір. Інші пишуть «конспект» **фіка,** поступово наповнюючи його деталями.

Очевидно, це слово вживається в 2-х значеннях: 1-синонім до **фанфік** та 2- на позначення авторів **фанфіків**.

Comment: Щось мені здається, що про _фік_ у значенні «автор фанфіків» — то помилка в джерелі. Такого не бачив ані в англійській (де _fic_ уже занесено в словники), ані в російській. Хоча теоретично все може бути.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, за фактом, [слово *фік* уживається](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014&word=%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA) в мережі:

> я десь читав фік, де Волдеморт повернувся привидом, бо встиг покаятись, але його знищили й як привида, бо забули(перестали про нього говорити, намагались не згадувати, ігнорували...) <sub>//З допису на форумі сайту hpclub.com.ua.</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Попередження: фік писався ще в ті давні часи, коли всі думали, що Кіномото Сакура – мама Шао і Вати-куна, тому прошу на це зважати. <sub>//[З примітки до фанфіка «Плата – фанфік» від автора Magnolia на сайті uanime.org.ua](http://uanime.org.ua/article/plata.html).</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Перш ніж викласти фік, напишіть шапку, що має складатися з наступних пунктів: … <sub>//[З презентації «Фанфіки на уроках української літератури: форми та методи роботи»](http://kramatorsk-movu.edukit.dn.ua/Files/downloads/%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B8.ppt)</sub>

Життя цього слова підкріплюється існуванням аналогічних слів у англійській (*[fic](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fic#Noun)*) і російській (*[фик](//ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA&oldid=94694768)*).

Але скільки часу пройде, перш ніж воно з'явиться в словниках (якщо не як розмовне, то хоча б у якихось словниках арґо/жаргону/сленґу) — невідомо.